# Counting the number of files, directories, and executables in the home directory using shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

so I am trying to write a program that will count the files, directories, and executable in the home directory. For some reason it doesn't read the right numbers for how many files there are, directories, or executables.
When I am in the command line it reads

```
ls ~/* | ls -f | wc -l = 31
ls ~/* | ls -d | wc -l = 1
ls ~/* | ls -x | wc -l = 5
```

This is my code and output

```
 files=0
 directories=0
 executables=0

 for i in ~/*;do
     if [[ -f "$i" ]];then
         files=$(($files + 1))
     elif [[ -d "$i" ]];then
         directories=$(($directories + 1))
     elif [[ -x "$i" ]];then
         executables=$(($executables + 1))
     fi
 done
 echo Files $files, Directories $directories, Executables $executables
```

Output is Files 14, Directories 2, Executables 0

Why is that happening anyone?

Answer (score 2):

- `ls -f`: will list without sorting. This implies `-a`. So, you'll get everything, including `.` and `..`, file or directory. It's not at all like the test `[[ -f $file ]]`. That's why `ls -f | wc -l`'s answer 31 is a lot larger than the 14 from your script.
- `ls -d`: will list directory instead of content. Without any argument, this is, logically, 1, that corresponds to `.` (it doesn't list the content of `.`). That's why you obtain 1.
- `ls -x`: list entries by lines instead of columns... so this is just not going to count anything relevant whatsoever.

Your script is nearly fine… except that because of your `if/elif` statements, the last test is nearly never going to be checked: executable files and directories will be `if`'d before!

You very likely want:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=0
directories=0
executables=0

for i in ~/*;do
    if [[ -f $i ]];then
        ((++files))
        if [[ -x $i ]]; then
            ((++executables))
        fi
    elif [[ -d $i ]];then
        ((++directories ))
    fi
done
printf 'Files: %s, among which %d are executable\n' "$file" "$executables"
printf 'Directories: %s\n' "$directories\n'
```

Comment: Ya only been learning bash for a couple of days so its pretty new to me. And yeah this is making sense.

Comment: Please also check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767112/read-command-in-bash-script-with-n1-argument/28767209#comment45813372_28767209 ... :) nice +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for directories first and next check for executable because **an executable file is also a file** hence your script never reaches inside this condition:

```
elif [[ -x "$i" ]];then
```

Here is the corrected version of your script:

```
for i in ~/*; do
    if [[ -d "$i" ]];then
       ((directories++))
    elif [[ -x "$i" ]];then
       ((executables++))
    elif [[ -f "$i" ]];then
       ((files++))
    fi
done

echo "Files: $files, Directories: $directories, Executables: $executables"
```

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, I didn't know you could also do the ((directories++))

Comment: Yes that is shortcut of `directories=$(($directories + 1))`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` and pipe the results to `awk`:

```
find "$HOME" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -printf "%Y %M\n" \
  | awk '/f/{f++}/^f.*x/{x++}/d/{d++}END{printf "Files: %s Directories: %s Executables: %s\n",f,d,x}'
```

Comment: See I tried using $HOME and it gave me Files 0, Directories 1, and executables 0. And i don't know why.

Comment: Hey I probably understood you wrong. Check my edit, does it work for you?

Comment: Hey so I was trying to avoid awk completely because I don't really understand it too well but my main goal was to figure out what was wrong with my program and why it is producing this output.

Comment: You can't reliably `for` loop over a glob. This is because file names can contain problematic characters.. That's why `find` is used for that. (You'll see tons of posts out there telling this since 40years)