# read command in bash script with -N1 argument

Tags: bash

Why does this script need the -rN1 after the read command (Specifically the N1)? Why would we want to pass only 1 character?

```
counter=0

while IFS= read -rN1 _; do
    ((counter++))
done < <(find /etc -printf ' ')

echo "$counter files"
```

Comment: For this, we need to know what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `help read`:

> ```
> -N nchars return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless
>       EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter
> ```

So this tells read to return after reading one character.

Each time one character is read, `counter` is incremented. So this effectively counts the number of files in the subtree `/etc`.

---

In this design (which is a poor design, see [@hek2mgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/171318/hek2mgl)'s answer for a better strategy), `find` spits out one space for each file found. Only one space (no newlines, etc.) for each file found. So you want `read` to read only one character at a time, so that `counter` can be incremented each time.

Comment: I guess I asked my question poorly. Sorry. What is the advantage of reading one character only? (Now thinking about it, it would be faster correct?)

Comment: " find spits out one space for each file found. Only one space (no newlines, etc.) for each file found"        BAM! I understand now!!

Answer (score 2):

`-N1` returns after reading a single char from input or if EOF is reached. No delimters are used. Typing `help read` read would have *helped* here.

The whole script counts files in a folder recursively and prints a whitespace for every file which was found. `read` reads every whitespace and increments the counter.

The command could be written simpler using `wc -c`:

```
counter=$(find /etc -printf ' ' | wc -c)
echo "$counter files"
```

... or even without `wc`:

```
counter=$(find /etc -printf ' ')
echo "${#counter} files"
```

Thanks to @gniourf_gniourf

Comment: Or without `wc`: `xs=$(find /etc -printf 'x'); echo "${#xs} files"`. I like this method, because with it you can do stuff like: `ts=$(find /etc -type f -printf 'f' -o -type d -printf 'd' -o -printf 'o'); fs=${ts//[^f]} ds=${ts//[^d]} os=${ts//[^o]}; printf '%d files, %d directories, %d others\n' "${#fs}" "${#ds}" "${#os}"` in just one `find` run.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yeah, that's nice! :)

Comment: I read the man page, but I don't understand why we would only want to read one character. Is there some type of advantage?

Comment: @William Advantage over *what*? How would you have written it without reading one character at a time? If you run that loop without `-N1` you don't get the correct results.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Just so I understand better what happens when you remove N1? I though a null character would delimit this and increment counter without N1

Comment: gniourf_gniourf solved my misunderstanding. Didn't understand the find function output. Now it makes complete sense. Thanks guys